# The centered text on images overlap on a grid using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

https://codepen.io/LifuTao/pen/JZaVNX 
THE HTML:

```
<div id = "element">
  <div class = "item" id ="box_one"><img src = "https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/2018-BMW-M4-CS-PLACEMENT-626x383.jpg?crop=1xw:1xh;center,center&resize=450:*" id="bmw" class = "car overlay">
    <p class = "text">Wannabe Baller</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "item" id="box_two"><img src ="https://assets.mbusa.com/vcm/MB/DigitalAssets/Vehicles/ClassLanding/2018/S/Maybach/BASE/GALLERY/2018-MAYBACH-GALLERY-001-SET-A-WP.jpg" id="maybach" class = "car overlay"><p class="text">Savvy Entrepreneur</p></div>
  <div class = "item" id ="box_three"><img src="https://icdn-3.motor1.com/images/mgl/nvEe6/s1/2019-audi-a7-sportback-photo-shoot-in-olso.jpg" class = "car overlay" id="audi">
  <p class= "text">I'm not like the other guys</p></div>
  <div class = "item" id ="box_four"><img src = "https://files2.porsche.com/filestore/image/multimedia/none/911-carrange-jdp-2017/normal/2269da21-2995-11e7-9f74-0019999cd470/porsche-normal.jpg" class = "car overlay"id = "porsche"><p class= "text">I know a lot about cars</p></div>
  <div class = "item" id = "box_five"><img src ="https://jaguar.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/636553494257956285DM.jpg?v=22" id = "jaguar" class = "car overlay"><p class = "text"> My car is the fastest in the land</p>5</div>
  <div class = "item" id = "box_six"><img src = "https://article.images.consumerreports.org/h_436,w_598/prod/content/dam/CRO%20Images%202017/Cars/October/CR-Cars-598-2018-Lexus-LS500-10-17" id = "lexus" class = "car overlay">
    <p class = "text">I'm better than them Toyota driving folks</p>
  </div>
</div>
THE CSS:

    #element{
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: [one] 200px [two] 200px [three] 200px;
  grid-template-rows:200px 200px 200px;
  position:relative;
  left:200px;
  top:100px;

}
.item
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#bmw
{
  max-width:100%;
}
.item:hover
{
  transform:scale(1.5);
}
.overlay
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.text
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:yellow;
    max-width:100%;

}
```

The code is above ^. 
The problem I'm having is that all the text gets jumbled into one another in the 5th box of the grid and I don't want that. 
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This overlap occurs because you are using `position absolute;` on the text. Per [CSS rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>       This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse with other margins.

Since the immediate ancestor of the `<p>` elements, the `<div>` with class `item`, do not have a position, the text is positioned relative to their next closest ancestor, the `<div>` with class `element`.

To get your desired effect, try give you `item` class `position: relative;`. Check out the results [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXRwJY?editors=1100).

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem